# Using VBA for Microsoft Word to find and replace a specific that has wildcards

Tags: vba, ms-word

First of all, hello and thanks for you help. So, i am new to VBA and i have to create a macro in word that finds a word, " **ID** ASD_PC_AWP_[xxxx]", [xxxx] being some numbers ranging from 100 to 9999 and i have quite a lot of these unique ID's in all my document. This i have to replace with : "[AWP_xxxx]. The problem i am having is that i don't know how the select in my code the **ID**. I was thinking to unbold the ID and than to delete the "ID ASD_PC_" so that AWP_[xxxx] remains but than again i have the problem that i don't know how to select that numbers. Thanks again for you help and time :) .

Comment: Would this be solved by replacing `ID ASD_PC_` with nothing?

Comment: You could just use the build in replace-function([Ctrl]+[h]) and replace ' ID ASD_PC_AWP_[' with ' [AWP_' .

Comment: I know that i can use ([Ctrl]+[h]), but i have to do a macro that does that automatically for the whole document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wish to replace

**ID** ASD_PC_AWP_XXXX

with

AWP_XXXX

To do this you need to use the Word wildcard option in the find replace and change the text you are searching for to correctly reflect the text presented in your image.

.Matchwildcards = True

.Text = "ID*ASD_PC_AWP_XXXX"

I have put * in the string because your image shows that there is either more than one space, a tab, or a combination of tabs and spaces in your search string.  You can check which they are by enabling invisible characters (Home.Paragraph then click on the backward facing P like character).  In the wildcard search the use of a '*' means find any characters so "ID*ASD_PC_AWP_XXXX" will find any sequence of characters starting with 'ID' and finishing with "ASD_PC_AWP_XXXX"

You can read more on wildcard searching here

https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Comment: Thank you very very much ^_^, this is the answer i was looking for. Also for the site, i am like very very new here, began doing this like 2 days ago with no support and all i have is the internet so i am trying to understand some stuff. And while we are here, because the next step would be to align AWP_XXXX with the **Menu** to be like **Menu** AWP_XXXX  and i found the command Selection.TypeBackspace but i don't where to put it so it will look like "Menu [AWP_643]"

Comment: you need to ask a new question rather than add a discussion here.  When you ask you question you should show the code you have tried..  Say what you want it to achieve and explain what is going wrong with your current code.  Try to make your question as specific as you can.

Comment: oh ok, that you for all your help and time :)